# I can not put a contract on to ethereum via Remix-Solidity by error - Invalid sender

Tags: ethereum, solidity, remix

I tried to run the following contract on to the ethereum blockchain,though,
I got a error of "callback contain no result Error: Invalid sender".

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;
contract SingleNumRegister {
    uint storedData;
    function set(uint x) {
        storedData = x;
    }
    function get() constant returns (uint retVal) {
        return storedData;
    }
}
```

The accounts[0] already has enough Gas and it is unlocked.

I have no idea of why this message occurs.  Please give me some advice to solve the issue.

//////Data of environment///////

IDE :

```
  Browser-Only Solidity IDE and Runtime Environment
 remix-4a2c813.zip.
```

Web3 Provider

geth :

> geth --datadir "/home/yuichi/ethe-prj/dprvnet" --port 30304 --networkid 1234 --rpc --rpcport "8545" --nodiscover --rpccorsdomain "*" console 2>./console.log
>
> instance: Geth/v1.6.1-stable-021c3c28/linux-amd64/go1.8.1
> coinbase: 0x91be0471171c5ddfe94cf5b3b81d1d1d5e9cab26
> at block: 9466 (Fri, 02 Jun 2017 05:35:45 JST)
> datadir: /home/yuichi/ethe-prj/dprvnet
> modules: admin:1.0 debug:1.0 eth:1.0 miner:1.0 net:1.0 personal:1.0 rpc:1.0 txpool:1.0 web3:1.0

Answer (score 0):

I found out the cause why this happened.  genesis.json was incorrect.
Actually config section was wrong.  I corrected like this:

```
"config": {
          "chainID": 10,
          "homesteadBlock": 0,
          "eip155Block": 0,
          "eip158Block": 0
  },
```

And I started again with "geth init" command again like:

geth --datadir AAA init genesis.json

And I created a node and started mining.  The error was fixed!